# How to get local resources in the Controller

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I'm trying to do this:

```
HttpContext.GetLocalResourceObject("~/Views/Shared/AnotherFolder/More/App_LocalResources/MyResourceFile.cshtml.resx", "myKey")
```

But I keep getting this error from within the controller:

```
The resource class for this page was not found. Please check if the resource file exists and try again.
```

That's if I wrap the call in a try block. Otherwise, the function is popped out of.

Directory structure, where `Views` is just right after the root folder:

[image: Directory structure]

I'm certain the path is correct as I just copied it from the resource file's properties window, but what could be wrong? Is the virtual path incorrect?

Here's the debug output:

```
A first chance exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' occurred in System.Web.dll
System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): Could not find stored procedure 'ELMAH_LogError'.
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection, Action`1 wrapCloseInAction)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection, Action`1 wrapCloseInAction)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.ThrowExceptionAndWarning(TdsParserStateObject stateObj, Boolean callerHasConnectionLock, Boolean asyncClose)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.TryRun(RunBehavior runBehavior, SqlCommand cmdHandler, SqlDataReader dataStream, BulkCopySimpleResultSet bulkCopyHandler, TdsParserStateObject stateObj, Boolean& dataReady)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.FinishExecuteReader(SqlDataReader ds, RunBehavior runBehavior, String resetOptionsString)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReaderTds(CommandBehavior cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, Boolean async, Int32 timeout, Task& task, Boolean asyncWrite)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReader(CommandBehavior cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, String method, TaskCompletionSource`1 completion, Int32 timeout, Task& task, Boolean asyncWrite)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.InternalExecuteNonQuery(TaskCompletionSource`1 completion, String methodName, Boolean sendToPipe, Int32 timeout, Boolean asyncWrite)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()
   at Elmah.SqlErrorLog.Log(Error error)
   at Elmah.ErrorLogModule.LogException(Exception e, HttpContext context)
```

Answer (score 0):

This [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms227982%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) article states:

> A local default resource file stored in the special App_LocalResources
>   folder is named according to the ASP.NET page. For example, if the
>   following code is used in a Default.aspx page, the resource file must
>   be named Default.aspx.resx.

You haven't said from where (or exactly how) you are calling:

```
HttpContext.GetLocalResourceObject("~/Views/Shared/AnotherFolder/More/App_LocalResources/MyResourceFile.cshtml.resx", "myKey")
```

Hence as the article suggests, if you are calling this method from within a file called "Default.aspx" (for example), rename the resource file to "Default.aspx.resx" and use this method call instead:

```
var resource = GetLocalResourceObject("myKey").ToString();
```

Note that I've assigned the result to "resource" as I assume that you are doing something similar in your real code, also note the need to cast the result to whatever type you are expecting.

Comment: Doesn't work unfortunately. I've updated my question with more details if it'll make a difference.